# Unable to call external api using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

when I am trying to call external api using spring boot from public network it is giving response, but when I am calling in from private network then it is giving timeout exception

```
ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, User.class, id);
User user = responseEntity.getBody();
System.out.println("User: " + user);
```

Also I am getting connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

There was proxy issue issue I have passed proxy settings in vm as argument and it is working